# Nighthawk X4 R7500 unable to view attached devices' bandwidth usage

Tags: wireless-router

In "**Advanced**" -> "**Administration**" -> "**Attached Devices**", I can see the list of devices attached, but both the upload and download speed are "**0Mbps**"

The settings:

- Access Control: Turned On
- General Rule: Allow all new devices to connect
- QoS Device Priority by Auto-Detection

Are there anything I am missing?

Comment: I have the same issue.